# Angularjs: ng-repeat rendering differes in Firefox , IE , Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Scenario: i have ng-repeat that renders 20 elements.

all browsers rendering perfectly but time differs , i have used directive to calculate rendering time

```
myapp.directive('postRepeat', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope) {
        if (scope.$first)
            startTime = new Date();
        if (scope.$last)
            $timeout(function () {
                console.log("## ng-repeat list took: " + (new Date() - startTime) + " ms");
            });
    };
}]);
```

IE 10: ng-repeat list took: 170-190 ms

FireFox 28.0:  ng-repeat list took: 200-250 ms

chrome 33.0 : ng-repeat list took: 30-50 ms

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZLGLHj2zMEEm9JlJ63h?p=preview

i dont know why its fast in Chrome where as in other browsers it slow .
is directive not calculating properly ?

can i have an expert opinion on this

Comment: Browsers naturally have rendering differences, since they use different engines. But it's hard to say if your test really shows the actual rendering time.

Comment: when i started using angular i had an assumption that i m using Javascript MVC framework now it seems m using chrome framework :s and abt test you can try it . it will produce almost same result

Comment: Can you provide a plnkr with the exact code?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZLGLHj2zMEEm9JlJ63h?p=preview

Comment: Won't the $timeout at the end distort the results? The console log will happen at the next `$digest` and not when `ngRepeat` finishes. Commenting it out made a big difference for me: http://cl.ly/image/1E460l1s2m38

Comment: @Ashesh you are rite abt it and it does make difference . thanku for pointing out . issue is more probably with directive thanks for helping me out

Comment: Even with $timeout, I get values of 40-45ms in FF 28. I think this method is simply to imprecise.

Comment: with timeout if u test in chrome u will get results around 8-12 ms so difference is yet there.